# How do I tell DataMapper to use "timestamp with time zone" for DateTime properties?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

By default, DataMapper creates DateTime properties of type `timestamp without time zone` in PostgreSQL.  I'd like to change that default for my project to `timestamp with time zone`.  How can this be done?

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't want to use UTC in the database and leave the TZ stuff to the display layer?

Comment: I'd love to... but I haven't found a way to make it work for my setup.  My web server OS time is set to PST.  I've dug down a bit and found that in the absence of a timezone offset being returned, the DataObjects driver assumes (incorrectly in my case) that times are being returned in local time.  For example, the database returns something like '2011-4-20 10:00' without the timezone offset, DataObjects actually adds the offset of the local machine to give something like '2011-4-20 10:00 -0700'.  So my UTC time comes out of the database correctly, but an incorrect offset gets slapped on.

Comment: So your problem is a library that's trying to be clever and helpful when it should be dumb and stay out of the way? Alternatively, you'd be good with DataMapper pretending that it is in UTC or just keeping its grubby hands of your timezones all together?

Comment: I don't know whether the library is being "too clever".  It's not a horrible assumption to think that incoming dates are local time if an offset is not present.  I'm sure others would find it annoying if it assumed UTC.  If I could easily get DataMapper to assume UTC if no offset is present, everything would be fine.

Comment: I tend to think that any assumption about timezones is too clever but squabbling about cleverness won't help you :) Have you looked at [dm-zone-types](https://github.com/hassox/dm-zone-types)? [DataMapper suggests](http://datamapper.org/docs/misc) that if you need to do anything with timezones.

Comment: I'll take another look, but it seemed that the problem was occurring at a lower level so that by the time it got to the dm-zone-types code, it had already incorrectly added the local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set ENV['TZ'] = 'your timezone'

Answer (score 1):

just in case some jruby users pass by:

you need to set ENV['TZ'] = 'your timezone' and

```
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.setDefault(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID('your timezone'))
```

'UTC' works fine for me. for other timezone you might need to dig into joda-time.